# CakePHP setFlash() weird problem

Tags: session, cakephp

I want to `$this->Session->setFlash('text'); $this->redirect('page');` but the message is not displayed.
I have included both the Session Component and Helper, and the `$this->Session->setFlash()` in my layout. However, after the redirect, the session doesn't contain any message. If I don't redirect, the message is shown.

So my question is, why isn't the flash message preserved after a redirect? It should be, and this how I've done before, but...it doesn't work now.

Thanks for any help!

Here is my controller code:

```
if(!$this->Test->__test_possible()){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Insufficient data to create test.', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

...my layout...(the cake default.ctp)

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

and the AppController:

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Facebook.Facebook');
var $components = array('Session', 'Auth', 'Facebook.Connect');
```

Comment: have you tested on other servers?

Comment: I'm currently testing on my localhost and don't have the possibility to test on other servers. But it is annoying, it has been working before! What could have happened?

Comment: and please post some code of your layout and controller.

Comment: hm, code seems to be correct. maybe facebook component is causing some session conflict? try to unload it temporarily.

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem...

Comment: Are you able to set session in traditional way. with $_SESSION ?

Comment: I put `$_SESSION['bla'] = 'bla';` in the controller and `<?php echo $_SESSION['bla']; ?>` in the view and it shows me a notice: `Notice (8): Undefined index: bla [APP\views\tests\index.ctp, line 1]`....

Comment: Oh darn...I've put `Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'Capitalize.me');` in the core.php and it seems he didn't like the dot in the name...now everything works fine. It's frustrating, really. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should post your solution below so that it helps others with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh darn...I've put Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'Capitalize.me'); in the core.php and it seems he didn't like the dot in the name...now everything works fine. It's frustrating, really. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

So we just chased down an odd issue where flash messages would not be displayed, despite having all the proper code. It turned out there was a space character after the closing `?>` in the controller file. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I was aware of that, but that wasn't the problem. I've heard this problem several times and have paid extra attention on this. Anyway, thanks for sharing the tip! It's really useful for newbies (and not only!)

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages are shown once and then deleted from the cache.  You're probably printing it before the redirect, which causes it to not show up on the redirect.

Comment: I've resolved the problem, see my comments above. Thanks anyway!