# CakePHP setFlash not showing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

setFlash stopped working in my CakePHP 1.3 app. The controller and view code is all there, and it worked last time I've checked. The problem is application wide, not just on one view/controller.

I'm aware of the space after ?> issue, and that's not it. Also, I read about a [missplaced dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586349/cakephp-setflash-weird-problem) breaking setFlash - that's not it either. Any ideas?

Comment: debug($this->Session->read('Message')); right after you setFlash, what do you get?

Comment: @Anh Pham - I get my setFlash message displayed as follows:

`Array
(
    [flash] => Array
        (
            [message] => Form validation error, please try again.
            [element] => default
            [params] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found what was causing the error!

The problem was BOM padding in app_model.php file, I've saved the file in Notepad++ with 'UTF-8 without BOM' encoding, and it solved everything.

Answer (score 1):

check that you have `echo $session->flash();` in your layout. If it's correct, try put `debug($this->Session->read('Message'));` again before flash() and see what you get.

Comment: I have `echo $session->flash();` in the layout. `debug($this->Session->read('Message'));` results in debug display of the setFlash message - the setFlash displays correctly in debug.

Comment: that's weird, maybe checking the css, and where you echo the flash to make sure it's not hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that's not it either. I've also checked the page source from the browser, and the setFlash message is simply missing.

Comment: ok. The last resort is debug inside the cake core, here's the code in cake/lib folder: http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/session-helper/#line-136 You can try putting debug in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Your message here.', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the Component & Helper?
I know it's trivial, but i failed with it once or twice.